# How do I have sed only perform actions on the first match?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

I have a bash script that extracts headers from the MIME Source of an email.  The idea is that I only want to capture the headers of the message nothing else.  It's not quite working right though.

I want it to do the following:

1) Start at the top of the email.
2) Isolate just the part that starts with "From" (my particular upstream mail server ALWAYS starts the header with a line containing this).
3) Capture all lines below it UNTIL the *first* line break.
4) Don't bother capture stuff from the remainder of the email.

I thought I could do it with this sed pattern: `sed -n "/From/,/^$/p"`

Unfortunately it triggers on other instances of "From".  For example, if someone forwardes a message and there is content like:

```
---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: Newsletter <newsletter@foo.com>
Date: Wed, Jan 28, 2015 at 9:16 PM
Subject: Blargenflugent
To: examplerecipient@domain.com
```

How can I have sed ignore content after the first line break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/From/,$!d;/./!q' <infile
```

...the above expression instructs `sed` to `d`elete from output all lines which do `!`not fall within the range of `/From/` through the `$`last line. Each time it `d`eletes a line it stops reading its script and starts over with the next input line from the top - and so it doesn't read the next command.

So the `/./!q`uit command means `sed` only `q`uits input on the first line following the first occurrence of `From` in its input which does `!`not contain at least a single `.`character.

Comment: I like this approach but the single quotes concern me a little.  Is there anyway to protect against malicious headers going into sed? For example, if a header had `rm -fr /` in it, how would sed handle it with the single quotes?  I thought double-quotes were preferred.

Comment: @MikeB - `sed` doesn't care at all about quotes - excepting the backslash, I guess. But even backslashes are for its script - not its input. You can print any amount of single quotes and/or `rm` commands at `sed`'s stdin and it wouldn't do anything but perform the text alteration commands as you instruct it to do in its script. The single quotes are for the shell in which you call `sed` - they instruct the shell not to try anything funny on the contents of that argument and to pass it along literally to the exec'd `sed` process.

Comment: Sooo, single quotes = good/safe.  Thanks  That explains why things aren't working quite right when I try `sed "/From/,$!d;/./!q"`

Comment: @MikeB - ah, yes. Shell expansions are interpreted within "double-quotes" and `$!` is a special shell parameter representing the pid of the last backgrounded process in the shell's process group. So it's either expanding that to nothing at all which would happen if you haven't backgrounded a process since opening the shell and which should result in `sed` not executing at all and quitting with error at invocation, or it's expanding to some number which could make `sed` behave the same or miss the match depending on whether the number is high enough to include it or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/From/!p;/From/{s/From/foo/;p;: rest; n; p; b rest;}' file
```